# JavaScript `addEventListener` with `submit` doesn't get called on some forms

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm learning by testing . recently I was playing with `addEventListener` when I noticed that the callback isn't always called when the form is submitted. 
To make sure the wrong isn't my html I tested on some websites like stackoverflow.

I seeked to the login page and after page load I opened chrome console and executed this code:

```
var form = document.getElementById('login-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) { 
  window.alert('form submission'); 
  event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

the same code works on facebook login page with id of form `login_form` so there must be something that prevents it from being called

I made sure the event listener is added in chrome Event Listeners tap, but when I submit the form either by click on the button or by pressing enter the callback is never called...

I don't get any errors in the console so the form already exists while I'm adding the event listeners and chrome already shows it was added

Comment: Did you placed the script in bottom of the page?

Comment: I added it in console after page load . the form was loaded so that I could grab it with its id

Comment: try window.onload = function(){} if your script is above the form

Comment: I said I'm using the console !

Comment: Come on, first calm and unhurried, this is a place to help and exchange knowledge. Provide a section of the form where the event is not triggered and a section where the form is triggered (html and javascript)

Comment: @AksJacoves I tested on facebook login page and the same code works with changing the id .

Answer (score -1):

There is one event call `onload` if you do not wait for the whole dom to “mount” there probably a chance that it won’t be triggered.

```js
window.addEventListener(“onload”, function () {
   var form = this.document.querySelector(“form”);
});
```

Comment: again ! I'm using the console after page have been loaded . if the form didn't exist I'll get error in the console .